# Difference between Tensorflow Operation and Tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused about the difference between Tensorflow Operation and Tensor objects. More specifically, what are the relationships between them and what are the design philosophies behind them.

```
x = tf.constant([[37.0, -23.0], [1.0, 4.0]])
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 2]))
y = tf.matmul(x, w)
output = tf.nn.softmax(y, name="output")

output
<tf.Tensor 'output_7:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32>

output2 = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("output")
output2
<tf.Operation 'output' type=Softmax>
```

If I want to pass output2 to sess.run([output2]), I will get None. Is there a way to convert output2 to output?

I am a PyTorch user, what will be the analogy of Operation and Tensor in PyTorch?

Answer (score 2):

I've not used PyTorch but you can assume it like it's a method and variable of a Layer class. So the operation is a method and the tensor is like the variable that can store the data. So when you run `sess.run([output2])`, you are trying to access the value of the method and not the variable.

To access the tensor from the name of the Layer, you can use the function as:

`output2 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("output:0")`

The `:0` is used as it is the first instance of the tensor. If you create more instances of the same Layer, it will be indexed as `:1, :2` and so on.

Edit: Another thing to note is that in tensorflow `sess.run([output])` extracts the value of output and doesn't feed it to the graph. Values are fed to the graph via using a feed_dict or a Feed Dictionary.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to rename "output:0" to a more meaningful name?

Comment: You can do it using namescope and a better layer name when you define the name argument in the Softmax layer. But the `:0` needs to be there as it is required by the underlying API for indexing. Also, naming the layers properly is good practice as they are critical when you are deploying your tensorflow models to mobiles and other applications where you don't have access to the layer through variables.

Comment: You can use `tf.add_to_collection`.

Comment: `tf.add_to_collection` actually looks like a better approach. Thanks @AbhishekMishra, I learned something new today!